How to prevent automatic handling of newlines killing performance in Perl text output?
TL;DR:
Automatic line end handling in perl5 seemingly degrades performance. Is there a possibility to mitigate this without sacrificing convenience by having to add newlines manually instead of using say or -l?

Long version:
I repeatedly wondered why my own (subjective) experience of string processing speed in comparison of perl5 (feels fast) vs python so grossly disagrees with the presumably objective performance comparisons on the benchmark game web page (e.g. in the fasta example perl is slow). What I found striking is: All world seems to use "say" for ordinary output, while the strange guy here sticks with "print" and manually adding "\n".
So I set up a minimal example:

Count from 1 to an arbitrary number in the language itself.
For every step output the number in a new line.
Repeat the whole process three times
Take the minimum time of these three runs while stdout is redirected to /dev/null

The whole thing was done for three different approaches:

Use perl's ordinary "print" statement and append newline explicitly every single time
alternatively call perl with "-l", which enables automatic newline handling (again with print)
3rd alternative: use "say" feature, which also handles this automatically

For every method I contrasted output buffering states (enabled vs disabled).
I was stunned, when I saw, that disabling the output buffer is far less detrimental for performance than enabling automatic line end handling -- the latter more than doubled the run time.
Records/sec  n_total Time Command
 7120052.46 10000000 1.40 perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\n";};'          
 4961279.63 10000000 2.02 perl -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\n";};'          
 2821234.16 10000000 3.54 perl -l -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};'                
 2462226.44 10000000 4.06 perl -l -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};' 
 2898328.96 10000000 3.45 perl -e 'use feature "say"; $|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'  
 2452486.23 10000000 4.08 perl -e 'use feature "say"; $|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'  

Question:
While for the time being it seems worthwile to add the line ends manually, this is still somewhat cumbersome: Is there any switch that I have missed here and that could prevent this degradation in output performance when using either "say" or the "-l" switch?

FWIW:
Couldn't help myself when I was already going down the rabbit hole. So I went on...
To get a more comprehensive picture I finally continued and compared the above to other tools I either use daily (mainly gawk, since recently also a bit of jq) - or did so in the past (python and even earlier tcl) or just dabbled around with at some time (lisp flavours). All on a windows 10 machine running cygwin.
Main criteria now was to choose the number so that it runs within 10 seconds on my mychine and still leaves the run numbers somewhat comparable (only powers of 10 considered).
Also contrasted using line buffer vs flushing output after every single line for some of the other.
The complete story is: disabling the output buffer in perl is less painful than in other languages (in particular python). For some I wouldn't even think trying it (see below).
 Records/sec   n_total Time    Command
 46772945.30 100000000 2.14 -- seq 100000000
  7102358.15  10000000 1.41 -- perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\x0A";};'
  4851147.42  10000000 2.06 -- php -r 'for ($i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {echo $i . PHP_EOL;};'
  4524956.61  10000000 2.21 -- perl -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\x0A";};'
  2643538.99  10000000 3.78 -- perl -l -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};'
  2542994.96  10000000 3.93 -- awk -e "BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10000000;i++) print i}"
  2537951.85  10000000 3.94 -- perl -e '$|=0; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'
  2407226.07  10000000 4.15 -- luajit -e 'for i = 1,10000000 do print(i) end'
  2347240.89  10000000 4.26 -- perl -e '$|=1; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'
  2342141.92  10000000 4.27 -- perl -l -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};'
  1869504.49  10000000 5.35 -- python -c 'for i in range(1,round(10000000)+1): print(i)'
  1641012.48  10000000 6.09 -- awk -e "BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10000000;i++) {print i; fflush()}}"
  1591311.72  10000000 6.28 -- jq -n 'range(1;10000000+1)'
  1395488.79  10000000 7.17 -- lua -e 'for i = 1,10000000 do print(i) end'
   905889.95   1000000 1.10 -- echo 'for {set i 1} {$i <= 1000000} {incr i} {puts $i}' | tclsh
   516841.54   1000000 1.93 -- python -uc 'for i in range(1,round(1000000)+1): print(i)'
   263998.59   1000000 3.79 -- clisp -x '(loop for x from 1 to 1000000 do (print x))'
   139282.21   1000000 7.18 -- echo '(loop for x from 1 to 1000000 do (print x))' | sbcl


used versions: Perl 5.36.3; Python 3.9.16; PHP 7.3.7; GAWK 5.3.0; Lua 5.3.6; Luajit 2.0.4;
jq 1.7.1; clisp 2.49.92; sbcl 2.4.9; tclsh 8.6.12; seq from GNU core utils 9.0

-l and say don't explicitly add a newline; they add the contents of $.  How does "print $i . $" compare?  (Ugh; dollar-sign and backslash.  Can't format it properly here.)

I would think that using the concatenation operator instead of comma is making a difference. In the very small margins of this experiment. I.e. use print $i, "\n"

@Jim Davis But $\  is ALWAYS added to print. -l doesn't cause $\  to be added, it causes $\  to be a LF.

on my xubuntu 24.04 laptop with the perl 5.38.2-3.2build2 package I don't get your timings. for the first 6, I see 0.88 7.55 1.96 8.54 1.88 8.45 - i.e. say and -l are largely equivalent (half speed of print) and the massive write() amplification for $| provides a major slowdown

curiously, I get <1 for perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\n";};' > /dev/null but ~2 for perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i};' > /dev/null. print "$i" / say "$i" instead of print $i / say $i also makes a substantial difference

@ikegami - Huh, neat.  perldoc -v implies it's not done if it's undef but that's probably semantics.

@Jim Davis, How do you suppose it knows it's undef? It has to check the value of $\ . Just like if it wasn't undef. This is done whether -l is used or not.

@ikegami - It checks, and either appends it or not.  So "$\  is ALWAYS added to print" isn't quite accurate -- that's what I meant about semantics, sorry.  I get your point that it's appended if it's set, I wasn't disagreeing.  (Also learned that say's newline is in place of whatever's in $\ ... I think that's what confused me.)

@Jim Davis, It is accurate. Whatever $\  is, it gets printed. Yes, $\  could have nothing, but that still requires the same access of $\  as if it contained something longer.

@ikegami - I'm not saying it wasn't accessing $\ .  I suppose I was misreading the documentation -- "If defined, this value is printed" seems to imply it's not printed if not defined.  I didn't intend to start an argument, and I regret making my misinformed initial suggestion.  Have a good day.

@Jim Davis, But the check to see if $\  is empty is the result of printing $\ ! Your argument that the printing doesn't happen presupposes that it does

TL;DR:
Simply quoting the numeric variable seems to resolve the issue with say and -l!

Long version:
After some comments above I carried out further tests. TLP and jhnc seem to be on to something:
When using , instead of . to combine the variable value and the newline for the print statement, that slows down the print call like using "say" did in the original post.
However, when the variable was quoted there was no slowdown. Likewise say and -l could be sped up again be quoting the variable with say being the fastest now. See tests below.
 Records/sec   n_total Time    Command
  6532779.83  10000000 1.53 -- perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\n";};'
  4812752.85  10000000 2.08 -- perl -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i . "\n";};'
  2851817.48  10000000 3.51 -- perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i, "\n";};'
  2292372.38  10000000 4.36 -- perl -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i, "\n";};'
  7081385.63  10000000 1.41 -- perl -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print "$i", "\n";};'
  5347508.00  10000000 1.87 -- perl -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print "$i", "\n";};'
  2957947.16  10000000 3.38 -- perl -e '$|=0; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'
  2611186.85  10000000 3.83 -- perl -e '$|=1; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say $i;};'
  7811974.89  10000000 1.28 -- perl -e '$|=0; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say "$i";};'
  5600668.93  10000000 1.79 -- perl -e '$|=1; use feature "say"; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {say "$i";};'
  2861258.14  10000000 3.49 -- perl -l -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};'
  2341549.60  10000000 4.27 -- perl -l -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print $i;};'
  7045289.66  10000000 1.42 -- perl -l -e '$|=0; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print "$i";};'
  4676765.18  10000000 2.14 -- perl -l -e '$|=1; for (my $i=1; $i<=10000000;$i++) {print "$i";};'

